# Android - App uses old resource ids even after update

Tags: android, r.java-file, android-update-app

I have been breaking my head over a weird problem. I have an app in the play store that was created using eclipse. Now I have migrated to Android studio. In the process a new R.java file has been generated with new resource ids for the drawables and other resources. Now when I try to update the app, I see wrong drawables. On further investigation I see that the the resource id's in the new R.java file are different from the old one but Android still refers to the old ids thereby resulting in wrong images.
Has anyone come across this situation? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yeah, I tried cleaning, rebuilding many times. Guess it is an issue with data caching. When I clear app data, it works.